# Using Likelihood Ratio Test and Bonferroni Correction with a Linear Mixed Effects Model with Random Intercept in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, likelihood-ratio, bonferroni

This is my first time asking a question here, so please forgive any issues in clarity. I am also a newbie, so hopefully this makes sense!

I am interested in comparing multiple regions of interest, a continuous variable, calculated from diffusion weighted images. I have a random factor of site as the subjects were collected from different sites. I want to include Sex and Age as fixed effects, along with diagnosis (I have patients and healthy controls). Using the lme4 package in R, I am calculating the linear mixed effect like this:

```
RVname.model = lmer(RV ~ DX + Age + Sex + (1|Site), 
data=datsetname,REML=FALSE)
```

then I am calculating a model without DX, as this is the fixed effect of interest:

```
RVname.model = lmer(RV ~ Age + Sex + (1|Site),  
data=datsetname,REML=FALSE)
```

Finally, I am using the anova function to find the significance of DX, the p-value (a likelihood ratio test).

```
anova(variablename.null,variablename.model)
```

I have 40 ROI, and am doing this for each region. I have many subjects.

My question is, if I want to use Bonferroni correction (p*40) to account for multiple comparisons, how would I do that? Would I do the Bonferroni correction on the p-value I get from the likelihood ratio test? And if so, how do I do this in R (multcomp package?).

Thank you in advance for any help in this matter!

Comment: I don't see why you have to do multiple tests in this case.  You can fit a mixed effect linear model without building separate models.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sorry, maybe I used the wrong term. I will try to rephrase it. I need to do 40 separate analyses, one for each region of interest. Each subject has a score for each region of interest. So each diffusion weighted imaging scan resulted in an average measure (my response variable) across 40 regions.

Comment: If you really need to do multiple testing with several tests Bonferroni may be too conservative.  There are ways to adjust p-values using the bootstrap or permutation methods.  This is given in the text by Westfall and Young.  There are also many other methods that do not use resampling such as Tukey's honest significant difference (HSD).

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check this out. But I need to use Bonferroni for this particular analysis (per my advisor). But in R, is the p-value I get from the anova function what I correct? I am assuming so, but I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly!

Comment: If this is a class problem you need to use the self-study tag.

Comment: "I have 40 ROI, and am doing this for each region. I have many subjects." Don't fit 40 models. Fit one model that accounts for `ROI` and then use the multcomp package for a post-hoc test. However, I don't understand how `ROI` can both be a continuous variable and something you'd do multiple comparisons on.